# Python - validate if an item in one dataframe column exists in the column of another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, postal-code

I am trying to validate a dataframe column `df['Postcode']` containing Scottish postcodes. I have two CSVs containing almost all possible Scottish postcodes (`small_df` or `large_df`), and I wish to loop through these and (for now) return the postcodes in my original dataframe that do not match any of the entries in these CSVs.

The data in each dataframe (simplified below) is a UK postal code strip of spaces, e.g. PA29DE, of string type.

| Case | Postcode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PA29DE |
| 2 | PH29AD |
| 3 | nan |
| 4 | KW102ZE |
| 5 | KW123DE |

I am using the following loop to do this, but it simply returns a list of all the entries in `df['Postcode']`.

```py
for i in df['Postcode']:
    if i not in small_df['Postcode'] or large_df['Postcode']:
        print(i)
```

I was expecting only the entries in `df` which are not in `small_df` or `large_df`. I'm really not sure how to proceed from here, and I can't find any other solutions which work.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did an error in your code, the 'or' is to test 2 conditions but `large_df['Postcode']` is not a condition so you have to replace it:

```
if i not in small_df['Postcode'] and i not in large_df['Postcode']:
    print(i)
```